# What is this special functor structure called?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, applicative

Suppose that F is an applicative functor with the additional laws (with Haskell syntax):

1. `pure (const ()) <*> m`  ===  `pure ()`
2. `pure (\a b -> (a, b)) <*> m <*> n`  ===  `pure (\a b -> (b, a)) <*> n <*> m`
3. `pure (\a b -> (a, b)) <*> m <*> m`  ===  `pure (\a -> (a, a)) <*> m`

What is the structure called if we omit (3.)?

Where can I find more info on these laws/structures?

### Comments on comments

Functors which satisfy (2.) are often called commutative.

The question is now, whether (1.) implies (2.) and how these structures can be described.
I am especially interested in structures which satisfies (1-2.) but not (3.)

Examples:

- The reader monad satisfies (1-3.)
- The writer monad on a commutative monoid satisfies only (2.)
- The monad `F` given below satisfies (1-2.) but not (3.)

Definition of `F`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Control.Monad.State

newtype X i = X Integer deriving (Eq)

newtype F i a = F (State Integer a) deriving (Monad)

new :: F i (X i)
new = F $ modify (+1) >> gets X

evalF :: (forall i . F i a) -> a
evalF (F m) = evalState m 0
```

We export only the types `X`, `F`, `new`, `evalF`, and the instances.

Check that the following holds:

- `liftM (const ()) m`  ===  `return ()`
- `liftM2 (\a b -> (a, b)) m n` === `liftM2 (\a b -> (b, a)) n m`

On the other hand, `liftM2 (,) new new` cannot be replaced by `liftM (\a -> (a,a)) new`:

```
test = evalF (liftM (uncurry (==)) $ liftM2 (,) new new)
    /= evalF (liftM (uncurry (==)) $ liftM (\a -> (a,a)) new)
```

### Comments on C. A. McCann's answer

I have a sketch of proof that (1.) implies (2.)

```
pure (,) <*> m <*> n
```

=

```
pure (const id) <*> pure () <*> (pure (,) <*> m <*> n)
```

=

```
pure (const id) <*> (pure (const ()) <*> n) <*> (pure (,) <*> m <*> n)
```

=

```
pure (.) <*> pure (const id) <*> pure (const ()) <*> n <*> (pure (,) <*> m <*> n)
```

=

```
pure const <*> n <*> (pure (,) <*> m <*> n)
```

= ... =

```
pure (\_ a b -> (a, b)) <*> n <*> m <*> n
```

= see below =

```
pure (\b a _ -> (a, b)) <*> n <*> m <*> n
```

= ... =

```
pure (\b a -> (a, b)) <*> n <*> m
```

=

```
pure (flip (,)) <*> n <*> m
```

**Observation**

For the missing part first consider

```
pure (\_ _ b -> b) <*> n <*> m <*> n
```

= ... =

```
pure (\_ b -> b) <*> n <*> n
```

= ... =

```
pure (\b -> b) <*> n
```

= ... =

```
pure (\b _ -> b) <*> n <*> n
```

= ... =

```
pure (\b _ _ -> b) <*> n <*> m <*> n
```

**Lemma**

We use the following lemma:

```
pure f1 <*> m  ===   pure g1 <*> m
pure f2 <*> m  ===   pure g2 <*> m
```

implies

```
pure (\x -> (f1 x, f2 x)) m  ===  pure (\x -> (g1 x, g2 x)) m
```

I could prove this lemma only indirectly.

**The missing part**

With this lemma and the first observation we can prove

```
pure (\_ a b -> (a, b)) <*> n <*> m <*> n
```

=

```
pure (\b a _ -> (a, b)) <*> n <*> m <*> n
```

which was the missing part.

**Questions**

Is this proved already somewhere (maybe in a generalized form)?

### Remarks

(1.) implies (2.) but otherwise (1-3.) are independent.

To prove this, we need two more examples:

- The monad `G` given below satisfies (3.) but not (1-2.)
- The monad `G'` given below satisfies (2-3.) but not (1.)

Definition of `G`:

```
newtype G a = G (State Bool a) deriving (Monad)

putTrue :: G ()
putTrue = G $ put True

getBool :: G Bool
getBool = G get

evalG :: G a -> a
evalG (G m) = evalState m False
```

We export only the type `G`, `putTrue`, `getBool`, `evalG`, and the `Monad` instance.

The definition of `G'` is similar to the definition of `G` with the following differences:

We define and export `execG`:

```
execG :: G' a -> Bool
execG (G m) = execState m False
```

We do **not export** `getBool`.

Comment: Do you have an example of a nontrivial functor which satisfies these laws?

Comment: yes, `IO` with the only operations `newIORef`, `readIORef` and `writeIORef` satisfies 1-2 but doesn't satisfy 3.  The reader monad satisfies all.

Comment: I think 2. can be generalized (via parametricity) to `pure f <*> m <*> n === pure (flip f) <*> n <*> m`. Functors which satisfy this are often called commutative.

Comment: The writer monad on a commutative monoid satisfies only 2.

Comment: @PéterDiviánszky: Isn't `pure (const ()) <*> writeIORef r x !== pure ()`?

Comment: I couldn't find an example which satisfies 1. but not 2., but I don't think that 2. is a consequence of 1. What do you think?

Comment: @NiklasB. I made a mistake, correction:  `IO` with the only operations `newIORef`, `readIORef`, and equality on `IORef`s satisfies 1-2 but not 3.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your first law is a very strong requirement; it implies that the functor can have no distinguished "shape" independent of the parametric portion. This rules out any functor that contains extra values (`State`, `Writer`, &c.) as well as any functor using sum types (`Either`, `[]`, &c.). So this limits us to things like fixed-size containers.

Your second law requires commutativity, which means that order of nesting (that is, functor composition) doesn't matter. This might actually be implied by the first law, since we already know that the functor can't contain any information other than the parametric values, and you explicitly require preservation of that here.

Your third law requires that the functor be idempotent as well, which means that nesting something within itself using fmap is equivalent to itself. This probably implies that if the functor is a monad as well, `join` involves some sort of "taking the diagonal". Basically, this means that `liftA2 (,)` should behave like `zip`, not a cartesian product.

The second and third together imply that however many "primitives" the functor might have, any composition is equivalent to combining at most one of each primitive, in any order. And the first implies that if you throw out the parametric information, any combination of primitives is the same as using none at all.

In summary, I think what you have is [the class of functors isomorphic to `Reader`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/representable-functors/3.1/doc/html/Data-Functor-Representable.html). That is, functors where `f a` describes values of type `a` indexed by some other type, such as a subset of the natural numbers (for fixed-size containers) or an arbitrary type (as with `Reader`).

I'm not sure how to convincingly prove most of the above, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! If (1-3) is isomorphic to `Reader`, then that is an answer to the first question. Could (1-2) be described in a similar way? Also, where can I read about "shape" and "parametric portion"? I am wondering how could I be sure about your insights. Maybe I could give a try in Agda, do you think is it a good idea?

Comment: @PéterDiviánszky: Sorry, those are my own terms, I don't think there are standard ones that mean what I want. Basically the "parametric portion" of a functor is whatever the type parameter is, like  the elements of a list or result of a function, and the "shape" is any other portion that varies between values, like the length and element order of a list or the mapping from function inputs to outputs.

Comment: @PéterDiviánszky: Regarding just the first two laws, my guess is that 1 implies 2 and that those alone give you a representable functor. Adding the third law only constrains the implementation of `Applicative` and `Monad` to also behave like `Reader`. That is, 1 and 2 mean the functor is isomorphic to `Reader`, but the `Applicative` instance may not be.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is quite enough to think about for me.

Comment: I wonder if 1 implies 3 as well. If the functor has a fixed shape, then you can't take a cartesian product, it has to be zip-like.

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher: I couldn't convince myself of that for infinite structures. For finite fixed-size collections, certainly.

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher: Surely not, `IO` with the only operations `newIORef`, `readIORef`, and equality on `IORef`s satisfies 1-2 but not 3.

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher: I added a simpler counterexample to the question description

Comment: The adjective for functors that are some form of Reader (such as fixed length lists) is Naperian.